# Directory appears as file?

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

So we copied some photos in a directory across to a NTFS partition last night, and they were viewable from ubuntu.

Today the directory is not accessible from Windows, and when we booted back into linux, the directory appears as a file and Nautilus thinks its a gzip archive.

ls -la gives the following:

```
-rw------- 1 kim kim 16769 Jun 17 22:47 DirectoryName
```

My assumption is that the "directory" and its pointers to the other files are still there, it just has the wrong attributes.

I tried

```
sudo chmod a+rwx DirectoryName
```

But this didn't have any affect.

Any ideas how I can convince my directory that its a directory again??

Or otherwise recover the files that are now orphaned on the drive?

**update and solution**

So I went home last night, tried to open the directory in Windows but it is still represented as a file in explorer. So I booted back into ubuntu to run

```
file MyDirectory
```

And the "file" is now gone. Not even appearing via ls anymore.

So we took a different tack, and recovered the files from the SD card using [this](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) excellent tool.

Thanks all for your help anyway

Comment: Does Windows use some sort of SSD cache device on that system?

Comment: No, no SSD on this device... just a single HDD

Comment: Let me venture a wild guess: what happens when you do `sudo mount -o loop /path/to/problem_file /mnt; ls /mnt`?

Comment: For determining what this "thing" actually is it is often helpful to run the `file` command on it.

Answer (score 1):

So I went home last night, tried to open the directory in Windows but it is still represented as a file in explorer. So I booted back into ubuntu to run

```
file MyDirectory
```

And the "file" is now gone. Not even appearing via ls anymore.

So we took a different tack, and recovered the files from the SD card using [this](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) excellent tool.

Thanks all for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus will normally just copy, unless you tell it to compress, which is probably what you have done accidentally.

The file is a file and not a directory, Nautilus can just display the contents of the file as if it were a directory. So open the file, and drag the contents to a real directory, e.g. one that you made under Windows before booting in Ubuntu.
The `chmod` command has no influence at all on the contents of the file as you already noticed, (older versions of) Windows cannot read such files compressed archives, and have a hard time when the proper extension is missing.

I would not remove the gzip archive file until you have verified you have viewable copies of the images somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

your `ls -la` output specifies that its a file not a directory

```
    -drwx where d stands for directory
```

if its gzip archive then you can gunzip it

```
    gunzip <filename>
```

Comment: Yes I know. Unfortunately, it WAS a directory node at some point, and it seems to have lost the +d somehow.

Comment: As in, 2 days ago it contained files, and after booting into Windows (who can't access the directory, probably due to permissions), it now appears as a file.